# Openlayers impossible zoom out to initial zoom level, when browser zoom changes

Tags: javascript, openlayers

The issue also occur here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Steps to reproduce:

1. set browser zoom to 100%.
2. click several times on "Zoom in" button.
3. change browser zoom to 80% and click zoom out.

Now you can see that you cannot zoom to initial zoom value, it doesn't allow you to do that. And clusters do not cluster to initial views. But when you change browser zoom to 100% again, you are be able to zoom out to initial zoom.

How that can be fixed? Any workaround? Is it actually a bug or it intended to be like that?

Comment: You are seeing the effect of the default `multiWorld: false` view option https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html as the viewport size (in pixels) changes  Specify `multiWorld: true` to avoid the constraint,

Comment: thanks a lot, you gave me a helpful hint, and I've found that option showFullExtent fix that behavior.